# Using an association as a local variable causes problems in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this make believe Rails model, a `Tree` `has_many :fruits`.

Inside a `Tree` model, I have the following line of code:

`fruits = fruits.joins(:seeds).ripe`

this tree does indeed have several fruits. However this method causes this error:

`undefined method 'joins' for nil:NilClass`

I believe the local variable on the left is causing a problem. For some reason, it causes the `fruits` on the right side to be nil even though `self.fruits` returns several fruit objects. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting 'fruits' earlier in that method?

has_many :fruits creates an instance method called 'fruits' in the Tree class. You would be making that inaccessible by reusing the word 'fruits'.